# Does defining cotangent space as quotient space work on $C^k$ manifold

Tags: smooth-manifolds

I saw three different definition of tangent space on [wikipedia#tangent-space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_space):

- via equivlent class of tangent curves: It works for both $C^k$ manifolds and smooth manifolds
- via derivations: It only works for smooth manifolds
- via cotangent space

I am curious abount if the third definition works for $C^k$ manifolds. On wikipedia the context is about smooth manifolds. I quote it here:

> Again, we start with a $C^{\infty }$ manifold $M$ and a point $x\in M$. Consider the ideal $I$ of $C^{\infty }(M)$ that consists of all smooth functions $f$ vanishing at $x$, i.e., $f(x)=0$. Then $I$ and $I^{2}$ are both real vector spaces, and the quotient space $I/I^{2}$ can be shown to be isomorphic to the cotangent space $ T_{x}^{*}M$ through the use of Taylor's theorem. The tangent space $T_{x}M$ may then be defined as the dual space of $I/I^{2}$.
> While this definition is the most abstract, it is also the one that is most easily transferable to other settings, for instance, to the varieties considered in algebraic geometry.

Thanks!